# List inside Class

Tags: c#, .net

Main Class:

```
public class ServiceResponse
{  
    public string RequestId { get; set; } 
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }    
    public List<FTTask> Tasks { get; set; }        
}
```

List Class:

```
public class FTTask
{
    public int TransType { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string TaskStatus { get; set; }
}

ServiceResponse sr;   // class object
int count = _SerResponse.Tasks.Count;      // count list items
```

How to find each param value of this list class inside for loop ...

```
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++){
       //     Unable to find TransType,status values of list inside this loop
}
```

Comment: `var item = _SerResponse.Tasks[j]`

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Reflection;

PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(Item).GetProperties();
for(int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
{
    string ParamName = props[i].Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain a reference to the list item.

```
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++){
     FTTask task = _SerResponse.Tasks[j]
       //     Unable to find TransType,status values of list inside this loop

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be the simple one

```
ServiceResponse rep = // instance of this class

for (int j = 0; j < rep.Tasks.Count ; j++){
     FTTask ftTask = rep.Tasks[j];
     int transTypeValue = ftTask.TransType;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track..see my addition for your script below. Hope this helps.

```
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++){
           //     Unable to find TransType,status values of list inside this loop
           FTTask fTTaskEntry = _SerResponse.Tasks[j];
           int transType = fTTaskEntry.TransType; //<- this is it right?
    }
```